# App fails to install on new JVC and Grundig devices(Amazon FireTV reject by amazon

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

My recent app submission failed due to:

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Purchase the app and install it from cloud

Actual Result: Observe app does not install

Expected Result: App should install successfully without any error message.

Affected Devices:

1. Fire TV Edition - JVC 4K UHD Smart (2019)
2. Fire TV Edition - Grundig Vision 7 (2019)
3. Fire TV Edition - Grundig OLED (2019)
4. Fire TV Edition - Grundig Vision 6 (2019)

However, there is a simple app and shouldn't be device-specific. Works fine for all other Fire TV devices. What is the deal with these new ones? I don't think they are even available yet to test...